# Why doesn't my makefile target-specific variable work?

Tags: build, makefile

I am trying to make a makefile which does the following:

- gets source files from the **src** directory
- puts object files in the **obj** directory
- puts binary files in the **bin** directory
- puts release targets in the **rel** directory
- puts debug targets in the **dbg** directory

The first problem i'm having is that my target-specific variables don't seem to be working here is the makefile:

```
# Build Directories
src_dir=src
obj_dir=obj
bin_dir=bin

cc=cl
cc_flags=

# create the directory for the current target.
dir_guard=@mkdir -p $(@D)

# source files
src = MainTest.cpp

# object files - replace .cpp on source files with .o and add the temp directory prefix
obj = $(addprefix $(obj_dir)/$(cfg_dir)/, $(addsuffix .obj, $(basename $(src))))

release: cfg_dir = rel
release: executable

debug: cfg_dir = dbg
debug: cc_flags += -Yd -ZI
debug: executable

executable: $(bin_dir)/$(cfg_dir)/MainTest.exe

# build TwoDee.exe from all of the object files.
$(bin_dir)/$(cfg_dir)/MainTest.exe : $(obj)
    $(dir_guard)
    $(cc) -out:$@ $(obj) -link

# build all of the object files in the temp directory from their corresponding cpp files.
$(obj_dir)/$(cfg_dir)/%.obj : $(source_dir)/%.cpp
    $(dir_guard)
    $(cc) $(cc_flags) -Fo$(obj_dir)/$(cfg_dir) -c $<
```

When I run make debug I get:

```
make: *** No rule to make target `obj//MainTest.obj', needed by `bin//MainTest.exe'.
```

There is also something else wrong because if I remove the debug and release variables and hardcode **cfg_dir to rel** I then get:

```
make: *** No rule to make target `obj/rel/MainTest.obj', needed by `bin/rel/MainTest.exe'.  Stop.
```

So my object rule must also be wrong.  I am new to make files so if anyone sees other things which are wrong, comments are welcome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Target-specific variables are only available in the recipes, not in the rules. This is because the rules are parsed when the Makefile is read, and dependencies are deduced from that.

To get your rules tailored for multiple possible values of `cfg_dir`, I suggest you look at the example in the [eval](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Eval-Function.html) section of the GNU Make manual. This explains things like this:

```
release: $(bin_dir)/rel/MainTest.exe

debug: cc_flags += -Yd -ZI
debug: $(bin_dir)/dbg/MainTest.exe

define template =

# build TwoDee.exe from all of the object files.
$(bin_dir)/$(cfg_dir)/MainTest.exe : $(obj)
    $$(dir_guard)
    $$(cc) -out:$$@ $(obj) -link

# build all of the object files in the temp directory from their corresponding cpp files.
$(obj): $(obj_dir)/$(cfg_dir)/%.obj : $$(src_dir)/%.cpp
    $$(dir_guard)
    $$(cc) $$(cc_flags) -Fo$(obj_dir)/$(cfg_dir) -c $$<

endef
$(foreach cfg_dir,rel dbg,$(eval $(template)))
```

Comment: That makes sense, I'll try to use eval.  Do you know why my obj rule doesn't work, even when I use a non-target-specific variable?

Comment: I tried to use eval but it doesn't seem to be working.  Is there any way to debug this?

Comment: You should list all the files your pattern rules applies to: prepend `$(obj):` to that rule as I did above. Also make sure not to mix `src_dir` and `source_dir`. With those modifications, and adjusting for gcc and its different options, things work for me.

Comment: OK, the `$(obj):` isn't needed if you get the `src_dir`/`source_dir` mixup sorted out. You could use an [implicit](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Pattern-Rules.html#Pattern-Rules) pattern rule instead of a [static](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Static-Usage.html#Static-Usage) one. But error messages are much more useful for static pattern rules. See [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Static-versus-Implicit.html#Static-versus-Implicit) for a comparison.

Comment: Thanks for all your help so far.  I fixed the src_dir/source_dir issue and I used eval like the example on the help page you sent me, but it doesn't seem to be running, make can't find the rules defined there.  I added a new question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11332523/why-isnt-my-eval-fuction-in-my-makefile-working.

Comment: I think you need to use `define template` instead of `define template =`

Comment: @payala: https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Reading-Makefiles.html#index-define_002c-expansion suggests both should work, and the `=` as opposed to `:=` makes the deferred evaluation more explicit.

Comment: In trying to figure this out myself, I've created a [repository](https://github.com/Asday/makefile-nonsense/tree/976b516e0210ba97449a0883802caab908ac9c5e/target-specific-variables-in-targets) demonstrating my solution.