# Why isn't my eval function in my Makefile working?

Tags: build, makefile, eval

When I try to run the following make file (updated with suggestions below):

```
# Build Directories
src_dir=src
obj_dir=obj
bin_dir=bin

cc=cl
cc_flags=

configs = dbg rel

# create the directory for the current target.
dir_guard=@mkdir -p $(@D)

# source files
src = MainTest.cpp

define build_template = 
# object files - replace .cpp on source files with .o and add the temp directory prefix
obj_$(1) = $$(addprefix $$(obj_dir)/$(1)/, $$(addsuffix .obj, $$(basename $$(src))))

testVar = "wooo"

# build TwoDee.exe from all of the object files.
$$(bin_dir)/$(1)/MainTest.exe : $$(obj_$(1))
    $$(dir_guard)
    $$(cc) -out:$$@ $$(obj_$(1)) -link

# build all of the object files in the temp directory from their corresponding cpp files.
$$(obj): $$(obj_dir)/$(1)/%.obj : $$(src_dir)/%.cpp
    $$(dir_guard)
    $$(cc) $$(cc_flags) -Fo$$(obj_dir)/$$(1) -c $$<
endef

$(foreach cfg_dir,$(configs),$(eval $(call build_template,$(cfg_dir))))

release: $(bin_dir)/rel/MainTest.exe

debug: cc_flags += -Yd -ZI
debug: $(bin_dir)/dbg/MainTest.exe

$(warning testVar $(testVar))
```

All I get is:

```
$ make
Makefile:41: testVar
make: *** No rule to make target `bin/rel/MainTest.exe', needed by `release'.  Stop.
```

You can see from the output that the testVar variable is never set.  I made these changes based on my last question: [Why doesn't my makefile target-specific variable work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11331390/why-doesnt-my-makefile-target-specific-variable-work)

Comment: Just a note: you might want to replace those `$(dir_guard)` lines with [order-only prerequisites](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Prerequisite-Types.html#Prerequisite-Types) in order to avoid superfluous calls to `mkdir`.

Comment: Also note that you might want to have the compiler flags set in the template, instead of inheriting them from the `debug` target. Currently, running make without argument will build `bin/dbg/MainTest.exe`, as that's the first target in the file. It will do so without the debugging flags. Even if you declare a target `all` up front, there might be situations where you want to build individual targets. It would be better to ensure that any object within `obj/dbg/` always gets compiled with the debug options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some spaces which confuse Make. Try this:

```
$(foreach cfg_dir,$(configs),$(eval $(call build_template,$(cfg_dir))))
```

Also make sure that you specify the right objects to link:

```
    $$(cc) -out:$$@ $$(obj_$(1)) -link
```

And as @Beta pointed out in the comments below, the `=` in the template definition syntax requires GNU make 3.82 or later. So better omit it from the line:

```
define build_template
```

Comment: I removed the spaces and fixed the obj error and I still get the same result.  I used the -p output and it doesn't look like it expanded the eval at all.  I also defined a variable in the template and tried to print the value using a warning but it was empty.  Are the any other debugging techniques you could suggest?

Comment: Strange. What Make are you using? Is this GNU make, or some other flavour?

Comment: Very strange indeed: using my make 3.82, the above works fine. You have removed all thee superfluous spaces?

Comment: The pattern rule has to start with `$$(obj_$(1))` as well, but even without that, I get `Makefile:41: testVar "wooo"` as expected. Running out of ideas here.

Comment: I'm not sure about this either (I don't use `eval` much), but I use 3.81 and I find that with `define build_template =` I get `Makefile:41: testVar`, but with `define build_template ` I get `Makefile:41: testVar "wooo"`.

Comment: @Beta: Good catch! This syntax using `=` really seems to be a recent addition, I can reproduce the problem using 3.81.

Comment: That did it, thanks guys!  What should I do now, should I mark this the answer, or should Beta add a different answer with the '=' suggestion?  You both pointed out errors in my code, I guess you can ro sham bo for credit.

Comment: @Beta, [ro sham bo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ro_Sham_Bo) sounds fair to me :-) Please only open my throw data:text/plain;base64,TXZHIHRocm93cyBzY2lzc29ycwo= (no [data URIs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme) in markdown???) *after* you decided; no cheating!

Comment: Of course, to really ward against cheating, we should rather [flip a coin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coin_flipping#Coin_flipping_in_telecommunications) ;)

Comment: Thank you @Farnk, but I think you should accept this answer-- I won't accept the credit when MvG contributed more than I did. Besides, quantum coin-flipping is so much cooler than the classical way.

Comment: @Beta, you can always write your answer to earn an upvote for it. As my ISP charges exponential for transferred qubits, flipping coins that ways is expensive…

Comment: Ok I'm going to mark this as the answer.  @MvG can you add the '=' sign issue to you main post just in case someone else has the problem and is too lazy to read all these comments.